# How to display parsley custom error message without <li>

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

Current, parsley custom error message is coming like

```
<li class="parsley-required">Enter User name</li>
```

And I dont want bullet point. I just need custom message in DIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the proper CSS, you can probably style it exactly like if it was a `<div>`.

If you persist in wanting a `<div>`, you can customize with `errorTemplate` (or using DOM attributes `data-parsley-error-template`). You can see [the defaults here](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/src/parsley/defaults.js#L51-L63).